# Flutter text to speech low volume on IOS-Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, platform

I'm facing a problem that `flutter_tts` package speak volume coming from Ear Speaker rather then Music Speaker.

Then I Just set following functionality for IOS platform

`await flutterTts.setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playback, [ IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker ]);`

Answer (score 0):

By This implementation, My problem solved. But for Android case It's going crash so make proper condition for platform as well like below:

```
 Platform.isIOS ? await flutterTts.setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playback, [
  IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker
]) : '';
```